# Babel only compiles js files of my Vue project, not the entire project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, babeljs

I have a Vue project that that I want to use on old iPad, running iOS/safari version 5. This means I need to transpile it to ES5 using Babel.

This is what my `babel.config.js` looks like

```
  presets: [
    //'@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
    ["@babel/env",
    {
      targets: {
        safari: "5",
        ios: "5",
      },
      useBuiltIns: "usage",
      "corejs": "3.6.4",
    },]
  ]
}
```

Now when I run `npx babel src --out-dir dist`, babel only compiles the `.js` files to the `dist` folder. No `.vue` files, static assets and `html` files are compiled/copied to the `dist` folder.

How can I get Babel to compile not just the `.js` files, and is there anything else I need to do to transpile my project to ES5?

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "sass": "^1.27.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-device-detector": "^1.1.6",
    "vue-material": "^1.0.0-beta-15",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not babel's purpose to compile static assets, you need either a bundler like webpack or a task runner like Gulp for this purpose.